# Can't center text on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css/html and I still don't know how to center the text when hovering. So I have a project on my subject to create a simple website. And so far I'm starting with the header. I'm having this one problem where I can't center the text everytime i hover my mouse to the menus. Here is the image and my code.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'crimson';
  src: url(fonts/Crimson-Bold.ttf);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100%;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
}
nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #7B241C;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 150px;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
.logo img{
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left:-60px;
}
li a{
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
nav a{
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: crimson;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
 
nav a:hover {
  background: #CD6155;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 50;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Pinoy Putahe</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
   <header>
    <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="logofinal.png" width="320" height="180"></a></div>

       <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#dish">dishes</a></li>
    </ul>

   </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Help please : (

Comment: You also want the text centered when _not_ hovering, right?

Comment: A common problem with new CSSers is to use too much styling, which adds unnecessary complexity. Here you have large margins and padding on your list items and anchors, which obscures the fact that your text _is_ centered. I suggest stripping those hard-coded values and moving toward a more flexible, responsive layout.

Comment: There are countless examples of such menus on the web and in tutorials. Use your browser's document inspector to see how they're done. Avoid floats, which are an outdated feature, in favor of flexbox or inline-block display.

Comment: `*` with `outline: none;` is a serious accessibility problem unless handled by hand troughout the application stylesheet - per element type.

Answer (score 0):

so many issues, and no need for such things, as long as u set one you dun have to set other, anyway I have just set the fix on the same code, you have to use `li` a or `nav` a, as long as they both are doing the same in your case, so I removed one of them both and you set `padding-left: 70px`, which I removed and added to the width of the buttons

check the snippet

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'crimson';
  src: url(fonts/Crimson-Bold.ttf);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100%;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
}
nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #7B241C;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 150px;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
.logo img{
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left:-60px;
}
li a{
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
nav a{
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: crimson;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
 
nav a:hover {
  background: #CD6155;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 50;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Pinoy Putahe</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
   <header>
    <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="logofinal.png" width="320" height="180"></a></div>

       <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#dish">dishes</a></li>
    </ul>

   </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```